# Designing for a 6in x 9in book

Tags: typography, print-design, page-layout, typefaces, style

I am putting a text heavy book together, `6in x 9in` paper size.  (Perhaps related are [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/what-are-the-basic-rules-for-designing-a-book-novel) and [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/how-can-non-designers-learn-to-approve-a-print-layout?rq=1) link.)

Now I look for good font pairings (nice examples are [here](http://cameronchapman.com/no-more-times-new-roman-font-combinations-for-book-design.htm)) and margin settings and line spacing that works well.  My current settings are `0.8in` top/bottom margin, and then `0.8in` inner and `1in` outer margin; line spacing `1.3`.

What are recommended approaches here, how can I set up visually pleasing pages?

*EDIT:* I would like to have a clean and simple feel to the book, while the text is readable comfortably.  Almost leaning towards sans fonts although I'm not too sure if that makes for good reading comfort.

*EDIT:* After posting this question and receiving heaps of good comments, I started reading the book ["Elements of Typographic Style"](http://typographica.org/typography-books/the-elements-of-typographic-style-4th-edition/) which gives answers to pretty much any question this thread raised, directly or indirectly. I'll post whatever typefaces and page settings I chose later...

Comment: [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/search?q=print%20a%20book) has lots of print tutorials, for all levels.
I have had great experience with Lynda tutorials in the past and recommend it as a great resource. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

Things to consider:

**Larger inner margin** not outer. A larger inner margin helps prevent text from being crammed into the gutter of the spine. If you don't leave ample margin for the inner side you may find it gets difficult to read text near the gutter with every additional page.

**Creep.** [Creep](http://www.printingtips.com/glossary-term/t--509/creep.asp) happens when books are bound. Each signature needs to be slightly wider than the previous signature so that when they fold and overlap the text remains in the same relative position while reading. Basically, inside pages are smaller than outside pages so text has to slowly "creep" to the outside the thinker a book gets. This is primarily a factor when perfect binding but creep can be a factor in some other bindery methods as well. To calculate creep you really need to determine the stock the book will be printed on. Any print vendor can generally provide you with a value to use for creep if they know the thickness of the stock to be used. If you "Google" how to calculate creep (if you are printing yourself), you'll get some general information. If your book is less than 12-14 pages then creep really isn't a factor.

Personal preference is to use a larger bottom margin as well. Visually things tend to drop or sink on a page. By using a larger bottom margin you help the perception that all things are well-placed on a page.

As for line spacing, that really is dependent upon the typeface to be used. 1.3 may be fine for some, woefully lacking for others, and way too much for others still.

Comment: Thank you for that information! Are you aware or resources that help me understand the finer details of typefaces, text/heading size and line spacing, and general proportions of the page?

Comment: THat's really a broad subject. There are books, courses, and mountains of information regarding those topics. It's not something which could effectively be answered in a Q&A format such as Stack Exchange sites. You might try narrowing your broad scope questions to specific items and asking those.

Comment: "Larger inned margin than outer" is considered wrong historically (and at least for me, this should be a still-true rule). The reason is that two pages when you have the book open should create a nice pattern of two columns of text and 3 visually equal columns of margins. Of course, binding has to be considered, which is larger for glued paperback than for proper hardcover. Therefore I would safely go with `0.8in` inner and `1in` outer margin. The top and bottom one should then be the same, i.e. `1in`.

Comment: @tohecz I'd go with Scott on this one. At the very least I'd discuss with the printer to see if the 0.2 will make a difference.I hate seeing text crushed by an inner margin or a fold.

Comment: @tohecz: is correct about the margins in a historical context, but I too personally make the inner margin slightly larger. Not a huge deal really: at least it isn't leeches. Regarding "creep", this is important information for hand-making your own books, but Jens should note that in the last 20 years I've designed books, I've never had to make creep adjustments myself: my print supplier handles this when imposing for plates. I do occasionally bind a PDF on copy paper for laffs and creep very quickly becomes a factor.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum You won't get text crushed in with 0.8in margin. You'll get about 0.5in margin (depending on the binding technique), which is just right ;)

Comment: That sounds about right: 100lb text is about .007"; ~42 sheets per .3 inches which gets you around 168 pages.

Comment: Thank you for the information, that's useful.  So it seems that I'm somewhat ok with all of the margins, but I would assume that these depend on the typefaces and sizes and line spacing and kerning that I chose as well?

Answer (score 6):

My two pennies; my first education was an apprenticeship in bookbinding... (book-geek, yes)

The classical way to define frames for content on book pages are based on the 5-7; and allow me to point you to CraigMod - he knows what he is talking about:

> [Image of page layouts](http://craigmod.com/images/journal/books_and_ipad/books-designing_books_01.jpg)
>
> [Craigmod - books in the age of the ipad](http://craigmod.com/journal/ipad_and_books/)

The construction of these things take into account a visual corrections; just as with passepartous for pictures.

edit:
Determening the printing area for books have been going on for centuries. There are two main, classical layouts:
Van den Graaf, who took "reverse engineered" old books came up with the 2:3 ratio:

[image: Van den Graaf canon]

Another tradition it to base it on Tschichold approximation of the golden section, a ratio of 5:8:
[image: Tschicholds canon]

Personally; though Scott gave a good answer, I would skip the creep (of pages! not saying Scott is a creep! ;-D). What is a very important element here, though, is *how many pages* you imagine the book to be, the type of binding and the weight of the paper.

I would *never* have equal left-and-right and top-bottom margins. The text-rich layout will give a feeling of text "sliding" or falling off the page. Consider the passpartous on well-framed pictures: they are equal left-right, but this is because there is no spine, no paper-bending/folding. The proportions of a passpartou is to have a larger margin on bottom than on the top. This will sometimes vary depending on the picture itself (darkness, colour of frame, passpartou etc), but the bottom should *always* be a little higher than the top. Some traditionalist say something like the combined width of left-right for the bottom. Personally; I adjust a little depending on the nature of the picture.

**Fonts**
As when it comes to fonts. This is highly subjective. Since your book will be text-rich/dense, I would go with a serif for the main content. There are many lovely and useful serifs out there; you are not stuck with Times New Roman. Personally; I would suggest take a look at Didot, Garamond, Bodoni, Hoefler Text, Palatino.

If you insist on a sans-serif make absolutely sure you use one that is well constructed. There are a lot of rubbish sans serif fonts out there. Guessing you might need æ, ø, å, pay particular attention to these characters. Excellent fonts of either type will actually have a slight variation on x-heights to compensate for a sense of heavyness. This example is Optima by Herman Zapf: notice the o going slllliiiightly lower, and part of the r slightly higher than its own stem. This is a sans serif with a softer feel; a hint of serif. It is one that actually works on longish texts.
[image]

For headings, quotes and other font elements: either use the same font, or go to the opposite. Be very, very careful about "arty" fonts. As someone said; you do not need a font that looks like dogs, to make the content bark.

Fonts will largely also depend on what kind of *feel* the book should have. Contemporary? Historic-ish (and if so, from where?) Arty? Avant-garde-ish?
I might be a little too font-geeky, but I found a book once, a story from London, set in an italian font some few hundred years later. I had to make an effort not to let that distract me :-D

**Line spacing**
Again; this depends on the font and content. And of course if you have a limit on number of pages. If you decide on a font and a font weight first, you must experiment with line spacing. It is entirely dependent on the font you choose. And... also dependent on wether you use a right-ragged or not.

Sorry if this was overwhelming.

Edit:
Quick-and-dirty suggestion.

[image]

Comment: While the links may help (I haven't followed them) I think your answer here might benefit from distilling the basic idea of what "5-7" is. Even if it is not "the" answer, it is still good information in some manner. If I google 5-7, I get bowling, and if I google 5-7 books, I get "goodnight moon"

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Late-night made 5-8 into 5-7 :-S This IS a pretty conservative book layout, but you could also say tried and tested over centuries. Give me a little time, I will edit some more info in.

Comment: Thank you so much, boblet!  This is exactly the kind of information I'm looking for... :-)

Comment: Happy to help, Jens. Feel free to ask away, I will give you two pennies worth :-)

Comment: You may wish you hadn't offered :-P  It sounds like the best way to approach that is to simply play around with different typefaces and pairings, vary margin sizes and line spacings.  Tweak them, generate the PDF or a printed (double) page, and look at it.  There doesn't seem to be a general how-to but just "dos" and "don'ts" directions.  I guess that's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Well, basically, there are a lot of traditional ways of doing it, and when in doubt, stick to tradition. Go ahead and break rules, but _know_ that you are breaking them. You could also simply pick down books from your bookshelf and see what works and what does not.

Comment: If you told me a little about what _kind_ of book you are making, I would come up with concrete font suggestions.

Comment: It's an English translation of a talk by the Buddha, with explanatory comments scattered throughout.  That's why I'd like to keep it very clean and simple with a bright and and spacious feel to it.  Yet well readable.

Comment: Interesting. You _could_ consider setting the main content in italic, as it is a talk; and the comments in regular. Anyway; since it is "wisdom from the ages", I would go for a serif for the text, but one that is slightly sharper with a vertical weight. If italic, you need to go up a notch on size. One Q: is your book 9in high, or 9in wide?

Comment: --- I ask about the width, because comments would be easier with a landscape format.

Comment: @boblet: it's 6in wide and 9in high, although this may be negotiable.  I've tried using Garamond, normal for the comments and bold or italic for the talk, but it felt "to heavy" or not quite light/clean enough.  Maybe time to poke around fonts a little more...

Comment: A landscape format would be more fun.. ;-) you could try something like the image I edited in in the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I'll try it out ;-)  Do you have a font suggestion in mind?

Comment: Heehe, I am a bit reluctant to suggest; but the VERY quick and dirty example have Didot 12pt/20pt italic, the same for blue comment except it is regular, and Optima heading. Agree that Garamond can get a little heavy; take a look at Italian fonts.

Comment: There are a few suggestions [here](http://www.thebookdesigner.com/2009/08/5-favorite-fonts/) but it seems these are all pay-fonts.  It seems hard to find decent free fonts for print?

Comment: Ah, Bembo. Good old days :-) These are classics that usually come with various operating systems or programmes like InDesign (or versions of them). Surely you have some of them?

Comment: Actually and unfortunately not on my 2006 Mac.  No Bembo, only one Didot, and rarely other typefaces that I read about and would like to play with.  There's also the challenge of diacritics, because part of the text is in Pāḷi and almost every typeface I have tried does not have the appropriate letters from the "Extended Latin Additional" Unicode space.

Comment: Ah, I see. The pāḷi would be a challenge. Maybe you have to do it the other way around; find the best Pali you can, and then find latin characters that match. And by match I do not mean "look like", but rather a font that complements. I see there are some Pali fonts out there; but since the characters  themselves differ so much from latin, there may be no real point in finding an "original" latin font with a Pali add-on. A Pali "Times" may not actually work very well with Times. You should be able to find free classics. Also; old OS technically _have_ the fonts, they just have different names.

Comment: ...and as far as I can see, you should have Apple Garamond, Baskerville, Didot, Hoefler text, Lucida, Optima, Palatino, Times..?

Comment: There are some pāḷified fonts out there, I might just have to spend some time noodling through them and see how they look when I build the PDF :)  As for the other fonts you list, yup, they're on my Mac and missing the occasional odd glyph.

Comment: Today I (finally) received the [Elements of Typographic Style](http://typographica.org/typography-books/the-elements-of-typographic-style-4th-edition/) book :)

Answer (score 2):

Aesthetically speaking: as much white space as you can afford; Rule number 1 is that more than 2 typefaces is not allowed; rule number 2 is that rule number 1 is made to be broken at will.

For "saddle stitch" books (folded, sewn/stapled), you want (need) to have multiples of 4 pages.

Squint a lot and make sure some/most of your blocks align or relate in some manner, especially across page spreads. This is the core for the "grid method" without reliance on an actual grid. Similar to typefaces: rule 1 is never deviate from the grid; rule 2 is deviate from the grid only when you know you are.

Comment: Rule 3: If you use Comic Sans, the Type Police will break down your door and arrest you. ;)

Comment: @horatio: "as much white space" as in wider margins and more line spacing?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: as sad/funny as the comment is, the original DOC file I received was entirely set in Comic Sans.

Comment: GOOD LORD - that is --- words fail me...