# 1960s Technical Diagrams fonts used by NASA

Tags: fonts

It's 1960, and technical diagrams are of top design quality, despite the limited technical means available at the time.

Which font would likely be used for the main text in such a diagram?

I understand that the titles often use Futura, but what about the main text?

It appears to be a variation of IBM Selectric's Letter Gothic, but I'm not certain.

Can someone direct me to a downloadable font that could replicate this?

[image: NASA APOLLO FLIGHT PLAN]

Comment: You can get [Letter Gothic from Adobe fonts](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/letter-gothic). It's not a perfect match. The numeral 1 is different. Also have a look [on google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?classification=Monospace), you can set the filter for monospace fonts and find something similar perhaps.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/1960s-technical-charts-sans-serif-all-caps-font

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1960s technical charts sans-serif all caps font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/1960s-technical-charts-sans-serif-all-caps-font)

Comment: I found the other post after this one, but I do think that I have already seen that one before in the past. It is my understanding that the other post is asking for the font used in the titles (FUTURA) while I was looking for the text used as body font. The other post however shows the guidelines in terms of fonts used at NASA for technical reports, and it seems that both DIRECTORY and ALTERNATE GOTHIC fonts are the ones I am looking for. 

I found a similar font to ALTERNATE GOTHIC but it is too bold, only suitable for small titles in charts. The DIRECTORY font seems to be a mistery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.myfonts.com/collections/letter-gothic-font-urw

I used the "What the Font?" app from MyFonts.

Comment: It seems pretty similar

Comment: Similar but not identical. Again the numeral 1 is different.